# Problem loading Geolocation in Lead Page

Tags: visualforce, jquery

I was trying to integrate Google geolocation capability within salesforce. 
Found couple of handful guide on net like the below. But anyhow was not able to get it working. Any insight into this would be highly appreciable.

```
<apex:page standardController="lead">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            varmyOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                mapTypeControl: false
            }
            var map;
            var marker;

            vargeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var address = “{!lead.Address__c}, “+"{!lead.Street}, " + “{!lead.City}, " + “{!lead.PostalCode}, " + “{!lead.Country}";

            varinfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: “<b>{!lead.Name}</b><br>{!lead.Street}<br>{!lead.City}, {!lead.PostalCode}<br>{!lead.Country}"
            });

        geocoder.geocode( { address: address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK&&results.length) {
                if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {

                    //create map
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(“map"), myOptions);

                    //center map
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

                    //create marker
                    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: results[0].geometry.location,
                        map: map,
                        title: “{!lead.Name}"
                    });

                    //add listeners
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        infowindow.open(map,marker);
                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
                        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                    });
                }
            } else {
              $('#map').css({'height' : '15px'});
              $('#map').html(“Oops! {!lead.Name}'s billing address could not be found, please make sure the address is correct.");
              resizeIframe();
          }
      });

functionresizeIframe() {
    var me = window.name;
    if (me) {
        variframes = parent.document.getElementsByName(me);
        if (iframes&&iframes.length == 1) {
            height = document.body.offsetHeight;
            iframes[0].style.height = height + “px";
        }
    }
}
});
</script>

<style>
    #map {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size:12px;
        line-height:normal !important;
        height:250px;
        background:transparent;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored your code and did some more changes(you can compare them in order you want to see the differences) and got it working:

**The changed code:**

```
  <apex:page standardController="lead">
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false
        }

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = "{!Lead.Street},{!Lead.City},{!Lead.PostalCode},{!Lead.Country}";

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<b>{!lead.Name}</b><br>{!lead.Street}<br>{!lead.City}, {!lead.PostalCode}<br>{!lead.Country}"
        });

        geocoder.geocode( { address: address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length) {
        if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {

        //create map
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

        //center map
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

        //create marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map,
            title: "{!lead.Name}"
        });

        //add listeners
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
                });
              }
            } else {
              $('#map').css({'height' : '15px'});
              $('#map').html("Oops! {!lead.Name}'s billing address could not be found, please make sure the address is correct.");
              //resizeIframe();
            }
          });

        function resizeIframe() {
            var me = window.name;
            if (me) {
                var iframes = parent.document.getElementsByName(me);
                if (iframes && iframes.length == 1) {
                    var height = document.body.offsetHeight;
                    iframes[0].style.height = height + "px";
                }
            }
            }
        });
        </script>

        <style>
        #map {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size:12px;
        line-height:normal !important;
        height:250px;
        background:transparent;
        }
        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        </body>
        </apex:page>
```

**Result:**

[image]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @CRMGuy, you've marked the other post as the solution to your question. If this is the actual solution, please uncheck the other post and check this one so users will know what you found the most helpful. In essence, I'm confused by your comments and wouldn't know which way to go if I were to look your question and both answers. You can also delete your comments to help avoid this confusion. Thank you.

Comment: Yes agree, actually I answered to his question exactly as was the question described.

Answer (score 1):

Visualforce now provides a dedicated  component integration maps in Salesforce.

[apex:map Visualforce Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_map.htm)

For your example, a simple map could be create like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Lead">
<apex:map width="600px" height="400px" mapType="roadmap" zoomLevel="17" center="{!Lead.Street},{!Lead.City},{!Lead.PostalCode},{!Lead.Country}"></apex:map>
</apex:page>
```

Assuming you save this page as *leadMap* you could call it via:

> https://< your-instance >.salesforce.com/apex/leadMap?id=<
>   your-lead-id >